# Time and work problem/algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this problem, and I don't know how to approach it. It makes me feel stupid to not get it.

First worker spends 4 hours less time for manufacturing 60 details than the second one spends for manufacturing 80 similar details. First worker manufacture 2 details more than the second one in time period for one hour. How many details manufacture second worker for one hour?

Comment: You could introduce variables/unknowns. Set $t_A=$ time worker A spends, and $t_B=$ time worker B spends. Then create the same variables for the quantities of the "details" ...

Comment: The core idea is that the "efficiency", that is how many details a worker makes per hour, is considered constant. So write
$$
E_A = \frac{q_A}{t_A} \qquad \text{and} \qquad E_B = \frac{q_B}{t_B}
$$
now plug in the known values ...

Answer (score 0):

HINT...if the first worker produces $x$ per hour and the second $y$ per hour, then from the information provided,

$$\frac{60}{x}+4=\frac{80}{y}$$ and $$x=y+2$$